# I Can't able to pass a values(id) in urls in django

Tags: python, html, django, url, primary-key

After user login their account,  it is redirect to home page. In that home page i added profile option for user to edit and view their profile. but logged user only view his profile.so i need add id in  url for show the specific profile page for the user.but i cant do that with my code. I need like this [" 121.0.0.1:8000/profile/1 or  121.0.0.1:8000/1/profile]..But i got this ['121.0.0.1:8000/profile/']    cant add  id in url and it throws page not found error

Views.py

```
class ShowProfilePageView(DetailView):
model = Profile
template_name = 'bgmiapp/user_profilepage.html'

def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):
    context = super(ShowProfilePageView,self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
    page_user = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    context["page_user"] = page_user
        return context
```

views.py/home

```
def home(request):
    profile=Profile.objects.all()
    return render(request,'bgmiapp/home.html',{'profile':profile})
```

URLS.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import ShowProfilePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/',views.home,name='home'),
    path('register/',views.register,name='register'),
    path('login/',views.login_view,name='login'),
    path('<int:pk>/profile/',ShowProfilePageView.as_view(),name='show_profile_page')
```

templates : home.html

```
{% extends 'bgmiapp/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Home {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h3> homepage coming soon!!!!</h3>
<a href="/profile/{{ profile.id }}">profile</a>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You want to show the user id on path?

Comment: yes, like this 121.0.0.1:8000/profile/1(1 is a profile_id) @usman imtiaz

Comment: Did you pass the user id when you are login ?

Comment: no sir,i didnt pass

Comment: Have you added the `pk` as argument in the respective view function?
`def view_function(request, pk)`

Comment: No sir i dont know how